# Cancel create when data is wrong

Tags: python, django

I have this class view which is connected to `Model`

```
class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data._mutable = True
        request.data['update_user'] = request.user.id 
        request.data['create_user'] = request.user.id
        try:
            isDataGood(request.data)
            .
            .
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except: 
            logger.error("data is not good")
            return Response(data={'error': 'This file is not pdf'}, status=406)
```

In create method, I check the data in `isDataGood`.

I want to do is like this below

- When data is not good, row will not be created.
- When data is good, row in the model will be created.

However, even data is not good, it makes the row in model `Drawing`.

I would like to cancel the creating row.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to raise exception in `isDataGood()` function when data is not good. Also I don't think viewsets are the place for making data validation. It should be done in serializer/model itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, I return the exception in isDataGood(), but data row is created already.

Comment: So, I guess I should do that in `model` or `serialization`.

Comment: @whitebear you shouldn't return exception in this case at least. What you want to do is ```raise Exception("Error message.")``` then it will handled in try except block. For instance when you ```return Exception("Error message")``` then it is NOT raised, so try except block have nothing to do with it, when you returning exception you can assign it to variable to raise it later for example, but this is not what you are trying to do. tldr: raise exception in isDataGood, then code you show here should work as you expect, but in terms of clean code better place to validate is serializer or model

Comment: Thank you I understood. This problem is solved, I think I have to find out another way to validate ,but it can cancel the creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data._mutable = True
        request.data['update_user'] = request.user.id 
        request.data['create_user'] = request.user.id
        
        try:
            isDataGood(request.data)
        except: 
            logger.error("data is not good")
            return Response(data={'error': 'This file is not pdf'}, status=406)

        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs) # Call the parent class's create method
```

Comment: What I want to do is not creating the rows in model. My explanation was not good, I re-write the article. thank you for your help.